# Infinite Loop in Stable Marriage Algorithm

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, infinite

OK so I'm officially at my wits end. I am getting this program to compile and run almost to completion. The last thing that is missing is properly going back (roughly speaking set i back to 0 to re-test all of the single men and try to pair them properly). Here's my algorithm. I am not sure why the end of my while loop doesn't work. Is there a better way to attempt to try and set "i" back to 0, after testing all the men, if the condition of someone being single is met?

Anything would be a great help.
Here is a picture of what should be going on:  [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3EVD.jpg)

```
//Check availability
    i=0;
    while ( i < ROWS /*(checkStatus(manStatus) && checkStatus(womanStatus))*/ ) {

        //Loop through man #"i"
        //for(i=0; i< ROWS ; i++) {

        if(manStatus[i] == -1) /*if man i is free, then:*/ {

            for(w=0; w<COLS; w++) {


                //Assign him the first woman on his list that is free:
                if (womanStatus[mPref[i][w+1]] == -1) { //if the woman in question is free (i.e -1 value), then :

                    E[i] = mPref[i][w+1]; //Row i, starting from index 1;
                    printf("Man #%d proposes to Woman#%d\n", i, mPref[i][w+1]);
                    printf("Woman #%d is single, and accepts Man #%d\n\n", mPref[i][w+1], i);

                    manStatus[i] = 0;
                    womanStatus[mPref[i][w+1]] = 0;

                    //Print the Women's Availability
                    for(j=0; j<ROWS; j++) {
                        printf("Woman #%d is currently:%d\n",j, womanStatus[j]);
                    }
                    //Print Men's Availability
                    for(j=0; j<ROWS; j++) {
                        printf("Man #%d is currently:%d\n",j, manStatus[j]);
                    }

                    printf("\nMan #%d is now engaged to Woman #%d\n", i, mPref[i][w+1]);

                    i++;
                    break;
                }

                //If the woman he wants is taken, check to see if she likes him more than her current engagement:
                if(womanStatus[mPref[i][w+1]] != -1) {

                    printf("Man #%d proposes to Woman#%d\n", i, mPref[i][w+1]);
                    printf("Sorry, Woman #%d is taken. ", mPref[i][w+1]);

                    //Check to see who the other guy is:
                    printf("She is married to Man #%d\n", E[mPref[i][w+1]]);
                    int oldGuy = E[mPref[i][w+1]];
                    int newGuy = i;
                    //printf("New Guy: %d\n", newGuy);

                    //If the newGuy comes first in the array, replace the old guy with newGuy
                    if(preferanceCheck(mPref, wPref, oldGuy, newGuy, mPref[i][w+1])) { //If this returns true, then new guy is better liked

                        //Set newGuy as w's current engagement, and then set oldGuy to -1
                        printf("Since Woman #%d prefers Man#%d, they get engaged!\n", mPref[i][w+1], newGuy);
                        E[i] = mPref[i][w+1];
                        manStatus[i] = 0;
                        manStatus[oldGuy] = -1;
                        womanStatus[mPref[i][w+1]] = 0;
                        printf("\nMan #%d is now engaged to Woman #%d\n", i, mPref[i][w+1]);
                        printf("Man #%d is now single\n\n", oldGuy);

                        //Print the Women's Availability
                        for(j=0; j<ROWS; j++) {
                            printf("Woman #%d is currently:%d\n",j, womanStatus[j]);
                        }

                        //Print Men's Availability
                        for(j=0; j<ROWS; j++) {
                            printf("Man #%d is currently:%d\n",j, manStatus[j]);
                        }

                        i++;
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
            printf("\n");

            //Test to see if people are still single
            for(j = 0; j < ROWS; j++)  {

                if(manStatus[j] == -1) {

                    printf("Sorry, but Man#%d is still single\n", j);
                    if(ROWS - i == 1) {

                        i=0;

                    }
                }
                if(womanStatus[j] == -1) {

                    printf("Sorry, but Woman#%d is still single\n", j);
                    if(ROWS - i == 1) {

                        i=0;

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    } //While Condition
```

Comment: can you only post which loop you're having the problem instead of entire loop?

Comment: As to not re-post, it's basically at the bottom of the code, beginning under //Test to see if people are still single.

Comment: Call me inquisitive, but what is stored in `mPref[i][0]` ? All your male preferences for females seem to start at one rather than zero, but the opposite is not the case. Just curious.

Comment: mPref[i][0] is the man himself, the remaining row is his preference of females.

Comment: So the `mPref` matrix is `[ROWS][COLS+1]` in size then ? Sorry for the boring question, but without a fully reproducible sample its hard ot guess what's what.

Comment: yeah, sorry, but without an actual [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) the best you're likely to get out of this is speculation at-best, incorrect advice at-worst. Clarity bring answers. Complete, reproducible code brings clarity, and "pretty much" isn't yes or no. Good luck.